# If I put a path after `.php`, the script is not found

Tags: apache-httpd, php, php5

On my Debian "testing" system after installing Moodle the request to
`http://localhost/moodle/theme/image.php/clean/core/1473903261/req`
returns

```
Not Found

The requested URL /moodle/theme/image.php/clean/core/1473903261/req was not found on this server.
```

(that is not only the image but the PHP script itself is not found!)

However request to `http://localhost/moodle/theme/image.php` returns

`Image was not found, sorry.`

(the image is not found, but the PHP script itself is found!)

So, as I understand, the script `image.php` is found only when I do not provide a path after `.php/`.

Why? How to cure it?

The server is Apache 2.4.23.

Comment: I've never seen a url where there is a forward slash after a fileName.php file, and then additional path after that. Apache is probably treating image.php like a folder named in that path. At that point it considers it not found before even considering the rest of the path on the end of the url. In a url, files occur after the final forward slash and all previous foward slashes indicate folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Apache config needs to have the AcceptPathInfo directive set.

If you have .htaccess support turned on you can add it in your moodle directory. Just add this line to .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

It can also be placed into almost any context in the Apache configuration files to enable it within that context.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo